# Need help using IntelliJ and setting up a project SDK

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk

When I try to run my program using IntelliJ it says I need a project SDK but when I try to set up a project SDK, it says "The Selected directory is not a valid home for this SDK"

Comment: This error message seems pretty self-explanatory.  Where did you install Java?

Comment: I'm not sure, how do I find out?

Comment: Do a search for the file `javac.exe`  ... Do you find it?

Comment: I found a Javacpl but not a javac

Comment: You might need to download and install Java.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when a java SDK is deleted, moved, or configured incorrectly.

Go into `Project Structure` (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+s)

On the left under `Project Settings` select `Project`

Now see the `Project SDK:` - it is likely red if cofigured incorrectly or it might say `<No SDK>`.

Firstly, just see if there is another SDK of appropriate java version in the drop down list you can use.

If not, you can use `Edit` button on an existing JDK to modify the `JDK home path` if it is wrong.

Or just press `New...` and `JDK` to set up a JDK that is already installed on your machine (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72`)

...if you have no JDK on your machine (be aware of the difference between a JRE and a JDK) then you'll obviously need to [download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and install that first